# How to use the command "with" conditionally without duplication of code

Tags: python, pytorch, with-statement

I am trying to use `with` before executing a block of code, but only if a condition is met, but (at least the common) usage of `with` doesn't appear to support that unless I duplicate the block of code.

More concretely, I know I can do the following:

```
if condition:
    with blah_blah():
        my_code_block
else:
    my_code_block
```

But that's unsatisfying during development since any change I make to `my_code_block` must be made twice.  What I *want* to do (conceptually) is:

```
if condition:
    with blah_blah():
else:
    my_code_block
```

That doesn't work, though.  Is there a way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

For anyone that's interested in my particular use, I'm trying to write code that runs a batch of examples in pytorch, with torch.no_grad() if I'm in evaluation mode and without it if I'm in train mode.  So what I want to do becomes

```
if mode == 'eval':
    with torch.no_grad():
else:
    run_batch(features, labels)
```

Comment: So, my_code_block cannot be refactored as a function to be passed into an executing function that contains the if block?

Comment: I would say no, but perhaps I'm misunderstanding your suggestion.  Fundamentally, I want to run `run_batch` with a context if a condition is met, and without it if it is not met.  At the risk of asking you to do more work, can you provide a quick example of what you mean?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `with` statement, but with a [`nullcontext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html?highlight=contextlib#contextlib.nullcontext) context manager if necessary.

```
from contextlib import nullcontext

with blah_blah() if condition else nullcontext():
    my_code_block
```

`nullcontext` takes an optional argument that it will return if your `with` statement expects something to be bound with `as`. For example,

```
with nullcontext("hello") as f:
    print(f)  # outputs "hello"
```

Comment: TIL I learned that nullcontext is a thing. Thank you!

Comment: StackOverflow isn't letting me accept the answer yet (too early), but it's exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: This answer would be even better if it mentioned that this is a case of the null object pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering if it could be accomplished with:

```
def myrunner(myfunc,usecontext=True):
    if usecontext:
        with blahblah():
             myfunc()
    else:
        myfunc()

def myfunc()...

myrunner(myfunc,usecontext=false)
```

But looking at it, I don't see how the context can effect myfunc.

Comment: I'd still need to modify both instances of myfunc's arguments if I changed how the functions worked.